# THR10X recording volume very low

Tags: recording, amplifiers

I have been trying to recording some guitar licks with the Yamaha THR10X amp in Logic Pro X. It seems to work ok, except that the volume is quite low compared to an audio interface (scarlett 2i4 in this case):

[image]

I tried the THR editor, but however I try to alter the settings, recored volume remains low. The usb volume options are greyed out:

[image]

Anyone used this amp for recording? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When you say "...compared to an interface..." Are you bypassing the audio interface entirely and connecting the guitar to the built in line in?

Comment: It's a scarlett 2i4, sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Do you have the guitar output knob turned down?

Comment: The amp is connect via usb to a mac, the guitar volume is max.

Comment: And the USB volume us also high?

Comment: USB volume can't be adjusted, don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - but it's just plain simple.

I figured out that the recording program (GarageBand) gets louder input signal if I turn the MASTER up - but then it got simply too loud.

Then it struck me. You can alter the OUTPUT (on the speaker) with the GUITAR knob - to whatever you like. Its the knob next to USB/AUX knob.

So one more time - put the MASTER volume up (it serves as input volume) and turn the GUITAR knob down. Now you have a nice signal and you can record at 2am if you want!

I dont know if its supposed to be this way - but it works like a miracle!

Cheers, keep rockin!!!

Answer (score 0):

From research into the USB amp, it seems that the only way you can adjust the input volume from the THR10 is through the track volume in GarageBand. The THR10 will provide a fixed signal, that apparently cannot be changed.

Either you can take the line out connection into the Scarlett interface and record that way, or carry just turn up the fader on the guitar track.

Try seeing if there is a newer version of the Editor software, and any Mac drivers for the hardwards. Contact Yamhaha support if the level is too low for use. It should be between 12 and 20db to allow for good headroom.

http://download.yamaha.com/search/product/?language=en&site=usa.yamaha.com&category_id=16173&product_id=1702689